# How to Upload image to firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I want to make function that users can upload own profile image and display in react native javascript:

- users can go to the image upload page and changing own profile image
- store image in firebase storage with user's uid name
- retrieve only user's image in profile page
- i want to upload picked image to firebase storage

I can pick and display image with expo-image-picker.

Code:

```
    state = {
    image: null,
    };
    componentDidMount() {
     this.getPermissionAsync();
    }
     getPermissionAsync = async () => {
      if (Platform.OS !== "web") {
       const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
        if (status !== "granted") {
         alert("Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!");
       }
     }
    };

    _pickImage = async () => {
      try {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
          mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
          allowsEditing: true,
          aspect: [12, 16],
          quality: 1,
         });
        if (!result.cancelled) {
          this.setState({ image: result.uri });
        }

        console.log(result);
       } catch (E) {
          console.log(E);
       }
     };
```

Comment: None of this code seems to upload the image to Firebase yet. If you have a problem with this code, please edit your question to indicate what specific line isn't doing what you expect it to do. If you're wondering how to upload the file to Firebase, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try converting the image into base64 format and insert it into firebase.